# Linker symbol arithmetic at build time computes wrong result

Tags: gcc, linker

I'm using GCC for a STM32 microcontroller application and I came across a strange phenomenom. I have a table of constant values in the flash which contain addresses from Linker symbols. Now I want to add another values which contains a computation (at build time) from two Linker symbols, but it doesn't seem to work.

It looks like this:

```
extern uint32_t _ls1;   // Linker symbol 1          
extern uint32_t _ls2;   // Linker symbol 2      
const volatile uint32_t table[4] =
{
    (uint32_t)(&_ls1),                    // 1. Correct value 
    (uint32_t)(&_ls2),                    // 2. Correct value 
    (uint32_t)(&_ls1) + 1,                // 3. Correct value 
    (uint32_t)(&_ls1) + (uint32_t)(&_ls2) // 4. Wrong value, always 0
}
```

The first three values in the table are perfectly correct.
Whenever I put two (or more) linker symbols in the computation, the result is 0. No error or warning is given.

Any ideas?

Comment: Doesn't `(uint32_t)(&_ls1) + (uint32_t)(&_ls2)` overflow? What are the values of `&_ls1` and `&_ls2` expressions?  `No error or warning is given.` - do you compile with `-Wall -Wextra`? `two Linker symbols` - can you hint how these variables are exported from the linker? Did you try using `uint64_t` or `unsigned long long` type for the computation? How do you check if the resulting value is correct or not? Can you create a smallest reproducible example [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)? Including the whole linker, main() function, includes, compiler, etc?

Comment: >Doesn't (uint32_t)(&_ls1) + (uint32_t)(&_ls2) overflow? It doesnt matter, what kind of compuation I try (plus, minus, xor etc.), the result is always 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have something wrong in your linker script.

I have tested it using my stuff (I am working now using STM32L476, gcc)

```
volatile const uint32_t test[] = {
        (uint32_t)&_edata,
        (uint32_t)&_sdata,
        (uint32_t)&_edata + 1,
        (uint32_t)&_edata + 2,
        (uint32_t)&_edata + (uint32_t)&_sdata,
};
```

(this table can only have automatic storage, otherwise it will not compile)

And the result :
[image]

Comment: Thanks. I checked your example and it did not work on my system (result is zero, again). There has to be something wrong somewhere...

Comment: definitelly - as I wrote - this example from the real project. Everything works fine.